# Unit Test Case for relatedtarget jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

Below Part is component where relatedTarget value is been verified
Component.ts

```
onFocusMethod(event) {
  if(event.relatedTarget && event.relatedTarget.id === 'test-id') {
    this.newValue = 'new test value';
  }
}
```

Below Code is spec file where to test related target

```
describe('relatedTarget test', () => {
  compoenent = fixture.componentInstance;

  it('should have value for property newValue', () {
    const elem = document.createElement("input");
    elem.addEventListener("blue", (event) => {
      component.onFocusMethod(event)
    });
    expect(component.newValue).toBe('new test value');
  })

});
```

Comment: You are adding a listener on `blue`, what is it supposed to do ? If you want to do so, you have to trigger the event before the `expect`, thus make the test async to wait for the event to trigger before expecting a result...

Comment: Sorry My Mistake its not blue, its blur event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like `Random` said, you should trigger the `focus` element on `input` in the `dom` of the component but to test it with just TypeScript you can do.

```
describe('relatedTarget test', () => {
  component = fixture.componentInstance;

  it('should have value for property newvalue', () => {
    const mockEvent = {
      relatedTarget: {
        id: 'test.id',
      }
    }
    component.onFocusMethod(mockEvent);
    expect(component.newValue).toBe('new test value');
  });
});
```